# Push notification in local web without internet

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm aware of GCM services for push notifications, but I have this issue.

I have a android app which will send a data to a local web server (php) that will response to another android device with the data sent, a normal push notification with GCM, I think.

But I need this to work even without internet, because it is a local web app that will work only that.

Is that even possible? Android device X send `json` data to web server that will send the data to other android device Y.

How can I verify that exists new data in the device Y ?

Thanks. I know its a little wierd.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. But it is not easy to develop. This is why:
Push notifications work attached to an account service. So you would have to implement an Authenticator service and then the whole push platform yourself.

I would not use GCM for what you are doing though. If it is working on a local network, you can use "polling" (request the server every now and then for updates)

Comment: the "poolling" method wont cause any troubles with that many requests ? I dont know how many devices are going to be used in the client-side, and the notifications need to be VERY accurate, so will be like N requests per 1~2 seconds.

Comment: then this is not your choice. Sockets maybe?

Comment: How i will use Sockets to verify an update on server? Could you tell me more about that?

Comment: If you use sockets, I would recommend you to take a look at the kryonet library. It is very easy to use and well documented:

https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet